# Does the HTTP Protocol support multiple content types in response headers?

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm wondering if I can return the response header

```
Content-Type: application/json text/json
```

or isn't this legal?

The HTTP protocol states that Content-Type should be of mediaType and that mediaType is defined as the following:

```
   media-type     = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )
   type           = token
   subtype        = token
```

But I'm having trouble interpreting what this means, can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `Content-Type`, as any other header, may appear twice or more.

Comment: @Stephan I don't think so: none of the escape clauses of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2 seem to apply to Content-Type.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to look at the definition of the header field:

http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.17

Content-Type   = "Content-Type" ":" media-type

so it takes a single media-type, which is defined by the grammar you quoted above.

So the answer is: a single type/subtype, followed by optional parameters.

Answer (score 5):

No. As pointed out in the accepted answer, the header value itself does not allow for multiple values, and it is also not allowed to send multiple Content-Type headers:

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
> name in a message unless either the entire field value for that header
> field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)] or the
> header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2

None of the "escape clauses" holds, because `media-type` does not allow a comma-separated list of values, and `Content-Type` evidently is not a well-known exception, either.