# How does .Net HttpClient manage to have multiple Media Types

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I am implementing an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept(v=vs.110).aspx) and noticed that the [Accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept(v=vs.110).aspx) property is of type `string`

```
 webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```

The implementation of [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) has it's [Accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.accept(v=vs.118).aspx) as type of `HttpHeaderValueCollection<MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue>`

```
clientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
clientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
```

Which means you can `Add` as much Media types to it as you want.

But according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809099/does-the-http-procol-support-multiple-content-types-in-response-headers), the standard only allows you to accept **1** Content or Media Type.

So, how is HttpClient able to support multiple Media Types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809099/does-the-http-procol-support-multiple-content-types-in-response-headers) you linked to is talking about the `Content-Type` header in *responses*.

You're looking at the `Accept` header in *requests*.

The server decides which *specific* content type (which may or may not match any from the `Accept` header) to respond with. This is a process referred to as [Content Negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation).

The specifics of how this works on the server side depends on the server technology being used. Here's an introduction to how it works in [ASP.Net MVC Web API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574797.aspx)

Comment: Ahh... Thanks for the clarification! They looked very much alike to me, since you can do `request.ContentType = "application/json";`