# body-parser get empty body when content-type have multiple values

Tags: express, body-parser

I upgrade from express 3 to 4, the body parse middleware has changed, so I use `body-parser` and it looks fine in most situation:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

But I have a 3rd party service, which will call one of my specific url to notify messages, it works fine in express 3, but failed in express 4, because `req.body` is empty

I debug the request header, found that the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; text/html; charset=UTF-8` rather than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

so I tested in curl, when I remove `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, the `req.body` can show my post body exactly.

so what should I do then? it's 3rd party service, it's no reason for them to change their code, is there a node way? tks

Comment: What 3rd party service is being used?

Comment: @ jm_____ a paypal like service in China called `alipay`, but will it a bit helper? it works fined in many platform even in express 3.

Comment: Do you any more code that you could include that show how the request and response are being handled?

Comment: @jm_____ hi, if you new a express project, you'll get the same error. i just create a new prof , and add a route: `router.post('/test', function(req,res){res.json(req.body);});`, and test in curl: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; text/html; charset=UTF-8" -d 'aaa=bbb&dccc=ddd' 'http://localhost:3000/test'`, it's empty, but if I change `Content-Type` to `application/xxx-form-urlencoded`, it can print my post body. will you want to have a try?

Comment: Can you edit, and include your code in your question? I was also wondering what the exact endpoint you are working with since it is sending back malformed `Content-Type` Because its should be `text/html` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not both. The other options however look fine. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5809704/2026508

Comment: @jm_____  yeap, it's malformed, and I printed it by `console.log("HEADER", req.headers);`. so the problem is that the request has two media-type, and the body-parser middleware treat it `text/html`? finally I wrote a middleware especially for this request, detect if there contains words `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then I `qs.parse(buffString)` solve it temporally

Comment: @jm_____ it's just a simple request I need to response, and it's post by 3rd party service, so it's just the reason that the service provider write some bad code?

Comment: Awesome! You are more than welcome to answer your question. Glad you were able to get it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according the doc http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.17, the request header of `Content-Type` is malformed.
so the problem is that the request header has two media-type, and the body-parser middleware treat it `text/html`.

finally I wrote a middleware especially for this request, detect if there contains words `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then I `qs.parse(buffString)` solve it temporally

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(/^\/pay\/ali\/notify/.test(req.originalUrl)){
    req.body = req.body || {};
    if ('POST' != req.method) return next();
    var contenttype = req.headers['content-type'];
    if(!/application\/x-www-form-urlencoded/.test(contenttype)) return next();
    req._body = true;
    var buf = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', function(chunk){ buf += chunk });
    req.on('end', function(){
      req.body = qs.parse(buf);
      next();
    });
  }else{
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just force `urlencoded` for Alipay like

  `app.post('/alipay', bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    type: function() {return true;}
  }))`

Comment: I will try by next time, since nowadays I work with OC