# HTTP Protocol support multiple content types in request headers using HTTParty

Tags: http-headers

It is stated that Content-Type should be of mediaType and mediaType is defined as follows.

media-type     = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )

But I need subtype to have ability to accept multiple values in the headers like **image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png** for content types.

Documentation shows an example like Content-Type: text/html; But I need an example which shows how to have multiple media types like image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png.

If an example using HTTParty method can be provided, it will be helpful.

Reference: (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#media.types)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the HTTP Protocol support multiple content types in response headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809099/does-the-http-protocol-support-multiple-content-types-in-response-headers)