# How can I display multiple Content-Type in a HTTP response message?

Tags: http-headers, httpresponse, content-type

In a socket programming, I must display multiple Content-Types.

ex)

```
Content-Type : text/html, text/css, text/javascript, image/png
```

However, this code doesn't work.
How can I display multiple Content-Type in a HTTP response message?
Thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the HTTP Protocol support multiple content types in response headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809099/does-the-http-protocol-support-multiple-content-types-in-response-headers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-Type` means should be **only one** type based on the requester's `Accept` parameter of a default content type you may specify, however if your client is interested in a specific type, it should send the type he wants in `Accept` request header and you should respond back with the requested content type.

requester may send multiple types through to say for example

```
Accept: application/json
Accept: text/html
```

which means the requester can understand both types. If server can serve and respond back in `json` format otherwise it should response back with `text/html`

More info on `Content-Type` header and other `HTTP` specs, please check [this](https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.17)