# Two different content types on one call

Tags: javascript

I'm posting to an api an object with two different params, each param needs a different `'Content-Type'`, the first param- `groups` should have the following `'Content-Type'`:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

And the second one:

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Is that possible to set a header with two different content types for the same post?

```
const { result } = apiPost(`api/emails/attachments?request=${request}&ticketId=${ticketId}`, data, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    });
  };
```

Ticket object:

```
public class ticket
    {
        [FromBodyAttribute] public Grouping groups { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<IFormFile> files { get; set; }
    }
```

ApiPost:

```
export const apiFetch: <T>(url: string, options?: object) => Promise<T> = (
  url: string,
  options: object,
) => adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api, axios, url, options);

export const apiPost = async <T>(url: string, data: object, headers: object): Promise<T> => {
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    data,
    config: {
      headers: headers || {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    },
  };
  console.log(data);
  console.log(options);
  return apiFetch(url, options);
};
```

Comment: It might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809099/does-the-http-protocol-support-multiple-content-types-in-response-headers

Comment: it will have to be FormData, and the JSON can be part of the FormData, or added as a header

Comment: @Slai I'm not sure I understand what you mean, could you please explain?

Comment: No, it's not possible, even if you add two Content-Type headers, the content body can only be of one type. But there is nothing preventing you from passing the `Grouping groups` as a json string in form data.

Comment: @AvinKavish Can you please give me an example on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, even if you add two Content-Type headers, the content body can only be of one type. But there is nothing preventing you from passing `Grouping groups` as a json string in form data.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('files', /* all your files */)
data.append('groups', JSON.stringify(groupsObject))

apiFetch(url, { method: 'post', data })
```

```
public class Ticket
{
  public string groups { get; set; } // <-- Try 'Grouping' as well, may work
  public IEnumerable<IFormFile> files { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Action(Ticket ticket) {
 var groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Grouping>(ticket.groups);
}
```

As far as I know, model binding does not deserialize json strings inside a form data binding, you will have to do it explicitly in your action method as shown above or by using a custom model binder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation!